# Emailer question using tables

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a simple mailer with html. I have been reading tables are the way to go and inline styling to be safe.

When I setup my td there is a space between that I can't seem to figure out why its happening.

here is a jsfiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/rcZZb/1/

As you can see there is a white space bettween the header and the banner.If I put another td below that there is a space between that too.

Comment: have you tried saving it to html and previewing it? I did and only happens in jsfiddle, not the file I made.

Comment: Are you sure the whitespace is coming from your code and not from the images themselves? Because it looks fine in my browser (Chrome).

Comment: Browser? I looked on everything I have (Mac + Win browsers) looks okay to me

Comment: On my browser firefox it shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `line-height:0` on the `<td>`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/rcZZb/4/)

Comment: well done, but that's a jsfiddle bug, in "normal" html it works fine without that property set.